# Numpy, Scipy and matplotlib cannot be installed in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have been having trouble installing the scientific packages of Python in both my laptop and desktop. No problems with scikit-learn though..

When I install using pip and packages from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

I always get this error message:

```
Collecting numpy
Using cached numpy-1.10.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy
Running setup.py install for numpy
Complete output from command "c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\
python\python35-32\python.exe" -c "import    setuptools,tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JAIMEA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-  build-qyc9cw52\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)  (__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record   C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-u0fbfg_0-record\install-record.txt --  single-version-externally-managed --  compile:blas_opt_info:blas_mkl_info:libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs'] NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaimeatienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaimeatienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaimeatienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaimeatienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaimeatienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\jaimeatienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaimeatienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaimeatienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaimeatienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaimeatienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\jaimeatienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaime atienza\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler
options running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler
options running build_src
build_src building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win32-3.5
creating build\src.win32-3.5\numpy
creating build\src.win32-3.5\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying  from distutils
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qyc9cw52\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1651: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qyc9cw52\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1660: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qyc9cw52\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1663: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qyc9cw52\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qyc9cw52\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qyc9cw52\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\jaime atienza\appdata\local\programs\python\python35- 32\python.exe" -c "import setuptools,tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JAIMEA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-qyc9cw52\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-u0fbfg_0-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JAIMEA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qyc9cw52\numpy
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have another version of Python on your computer, check if your modules are installed on that version instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to install numpy, scipy etc using pip, especially on Windows, you'll have all sorts of pain trying to compile the C source; these days it's much better to use a scipy distribution like Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that

Comment: I installed Anaconda in my machine and it worked wonders for me! Thanks!